# HTML & CSS, Buttons in iOS take up all the space

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm currently working on a web application and I'm facing an issue, the buttons in ios devices (tested in both safari and chrome) take up all space available, while on Android devices, they appear as expected.

******* **in android**:
[image]

******* **in ios**:
[image]

the buttons tags:

```
   <div className="divButtonsMenuHeader">
      <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <SearchIcon height="1.4rem" />
      </button>
      <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <BagIcon height="1.4rem" />
      </button>
      <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <HeartIcon height="1.4rem" />
      </button>
      <button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} className='test'>
        <ProfileIcon height="1.4rem" />
      </button>
    </div>
```

and css of class divButtonsMenuHeader:

```
.divButtonsMenuHeader {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   gap: 1rem;
}
```

thank you for you time